# Erro ao salvar informações de formulário PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados, formulário

**O que está acontecendo:**

Tenho um sistema que, ao terminar de preencher o formulário e salvar, não salva as alterações aparecendo um `alert` de "salvo sem alterações" e voltando pra página anterior.

**O que deveria acontecer:**

Ao tentar salvar o formulário, deveria aparecer o script de Salvo com sucesso e voltar pra página anterior.

Como eu não domino essa linguagem, não estou encontrando onde está a lógica responsável por reconhecer que um campo foi mudado e salvar. 
Acredito que o erro esteja no formulário, já que não tem nada de errado com o banco nem com a conexão.
Como não posso colocar o sistema todo aqui, vou colocar algumas partes que eu acredite que possam ser responsáveis pelo erro:

**Encontra o ID do que se quer alterar**

```
<?php
// Busca valores no banco de dados para preenchimento do formulario para alterar
$id = $_GET['id'];
$sql = (" SELECT * FROM re WHERE id = '{$id}'");
$query=mysql_query($sql);
while ($campo = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {  
?>
```

**parte do formulário**

```
<div class="container">
    <form method="post" action="../std/update.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="re" class="formulario">
        <div class="container container-divisor">
            <h4>Descrição Re</h4>
            <div class="row">
                <input type="hidden" name="idnovo" id="idnovo" value="<?=$campo['id'];?>">
                <input type="hidden" name="dataedicao" id="dataedicao" value="<?php echo date('d/m/Y'); ?>">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <label for="datacriacao">Data</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="datacriacao" id="dataCriacao" value="<?=$campo['datacriacao'];?>"127>
                </div>
          </div>
    </form>
```

**Na página responsável por atualizar o banco, os textos em js:**

```
<?php
    if(mysql_affected_rows() > 0){
    ?>  
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert("Salvo com Sucesso !");
    window.history.go(-1);
</script>

<?php
        }
        else{
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert("Salvo sem Modificações !");
    window.history.go(-1);
</script>
<?php           
        } 
mysql_close($conexao);
?>
```

**A página update**

```
<?php 
include ("conecta.php");

//coletando dados do formulario

    $id             =   $_POST["idnovo"]; 
    $dataedicao     =   $_POST["dataedicao"];
    $datacriacao    =   $_POST["datacriacao"];
    $statusgeral    =   $_POST["statusgeral"];
    $criadopor      =   $_POST["criadopor"];


// Inserir dados no banco
    $itens = $_POST['meti'];
//$_POST['meti'] as $itens
    if (!empty($itens)){
 $itens = implode(',', $_POST['meti']);
}



$up= mysql_query("UPDATE retex SET dataedicao = '$dataedicao', datacriacao = '$datacriacao', statusgeral = '$statusgeral', criadopor = '$criadopor' WHERE id = '$id' ");

?>
<?php
    if(mysql_affected_rows() > 0){
    ?>  
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert("Salvo com Sucesso !");
    window.history.go(-1);
</script>

<?php
        }
        else{
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert("Salvo sem Modificações !");
    window.history.go(-1);
</script>
<?php           
        } 
mysql_close($conexao);
?>
```

Eu acredito que o formulário não esteja reconhecendo que um campo foi alterado, mas é só uma hipótese. Conforme eu for descobrindo mais coisas eu edito.

Comment: Amigo, não use mysql ja está descontinuado, utilize mysqli e tem outra coisa aqui utilize assim $sql = " SELECT * FROM re WHERE id = '{$id}' "; se não o php considera como texto, tente isso e de o retorno, abraços

Comment: Mariana após o ´while´ altere sua pergunta e cole todo o código de update. Sem aquela parte não tem muito como ajudar

Comment: Então, mudando todos os mysql_query para mysqli_query, tanto no update, tanto na conexão quanto na página do formulário, o conteúdo sumiu, dando a mensagem "NULL" -@AndersonHenrique

Comment: Creio que seria melhor você separar tudo. Tipo php pra um arquivo, html pra outro  e javascript pra outro. Fica mais legível o código

Comment: Então, os scripts estão no final da página update, responsável pelo banco. A página altera é a página responsável por montar o formulário e o código que reconhece o ID está no início dela. Ou seja, foram postados os códigos de duas páginas.

Comment: @adventistaam .

Comment: tipo os javascript estão dentro do php. Tente também usar mysqli como sugerido pelo @AndersonHenrique

Comment: Então, eu não posso mudar pra mysqli por causa da minha versão do php que é antiga.

Comment: No seu update tem o seguinte `SET dataedicao = '$dataedicao',' `  tem uma virgula após a aspas simples **','** remova a virgula e a aspas simples à direita. O que ficaria  `SET dataedicao = '$dataedicao'`

Comment: Editei e coloquei mais informações no formulário e no banco pra você entender como eu tava fazendo (Antes foi um erro na hora de digitar a questão. desculpa)

Comment: Seu arquivo conecta está normal? Está selecionando o banco?

Comment: Sim, o banco está conectando, tanto que quando eu seleciono um id de formulário carrega todas as informações da ultima edição. Só não salva as novas edições.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62855/discussion-between-mariana-ferreira-and-adventistaam).

Comment: tente dar um echo em cada campo pra ver se o id está indo.. porque se nao tive id ele nao altera

Comment: O ID vai, tanto que as ultimas edições feitas, salvas naquele ID, carregam. Só que o campo não tá reconhecendo que algo foi digitado nele. e por isso aparece o alert de "salvo sem modificações".